# Почему в OpenGL на Python получаю треугольник вместо икосаэдра?

Tags: python, opengl

Пытаюсь получить икосаэдр. Причем через вершины, а не определение индексов. Однако на выходе имею треугольник вместо полноценного икосаэдра. Что делаю не так?

Код

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt 

# 1. инициализация библиотеки glfw
if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception('Бибиотека glfw не может быть инициализирована')

# 2. создаем окно
window = glfw.create_window(1280, 720, 'Моя программа', None, None)

# 3. проверим, правильно ли окно было создано
if not window:
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception('Окно glfw не может быть создано')

# 4. установим положение окна
glfw.set_window_pos(window, 400, 200)
    
# 5. установим функцию обратного вызова для изменения размера окна;
glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize)

# 6. функция изменения размера окна
def window_resize(window, width, height): 
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    
# 7. сделаем контекст текущим (передадим фунции переменную window)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

scale = 1

# 8. Возвращаем координаты вершин икосаэндра
def vertex(x, y, z):
    length = sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    return [(i * scale) / length for i in (x,y,z)]

# 9.Создаем икосаэдр
# Золотое сечение
PHI = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
# 9.1. вершины
vertices = [
          vertex(-1,  PHI, 0), 
          vertex( 1,  PHI, 0), 
          vertex(-1, -PHI, 0), 
          vertex( 1, -PHI, 0), 

          vertex(0, -1, PHI), 
          vertex(0,  1, PHI), 
          vertex(0, -1, -PHI), 
          vertex(0,  1, -PHI), 

          vertex( PHI, 0, -1), 
          vertex( PHI, 0,  1), 
          vertex(-PHI, 0, -1), 
          vertex(-PHI, 0,  1)
    ]
# 9.2. цвета вершин
colors = [  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0,

            0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

            1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0   ]

# 10. преобразуем списки Python в массивы numpy
vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)
colors = np.array(colors, dtype=np.float32)

# 11. "включим" массивы вершин и цветов вершин
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices)

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors)

# 12. определим цвет фона
glClearColor(0, 0.1, 0.1, 1)

# 13. создадим основной цикл приложения
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    # обеспечим ответ на курсор мышки
    glfw.poll_events()
    
    # функция, которая позволит увидеть эффект настройки цветов в строке glClearColor(0, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    
    # заменим текущую матрицу на идентификационную матрицу
    glLoadIdentity()
    
    # определим примитив для отображения.
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
     
    # здесь используется двойная буферизация кадров (задний отрисоывает, передний - показывает)
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)

# 14. закроем glfw, освободим выделенные ресурсы памяти 
glfw.terminate()
```

Comment: Подозреваю что вектор координат точек должен быть линейным. А у вас он двумерный.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, а как добиться линейности? мне казалось, что многомерным массив был бы, если б  я каждую точку поместил в список вроде того `[vertex(-1,  PHI, 0)]`

Comment: Функция `vertex` возвращает список. Вы собираете списки в список списков - двумерный массив. Перепишите все координаты в общий одномерный массив размера *3 * число_точек*.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, добавил строку `vertices = np.array(vertices).flatten()`, но результат пока тот же (

Comment: Ещё одна вещь: в икосаэдре 20 треугольников - 60 вершин. Вы рисуете треугольниками, но где 60 вершин в массиве? Всего должно быть 180 чисел.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, в икосаэдре, насколько понимаю, вершин 12

Comment: Да, вершин - 12. Каждая должна повторится пять раз, так как встречается в пяти разных треугольниках. Которые вы передаёте списком из вершин.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, Вы правы. Поначалу я попробовал указывать на вершины через индексы, чтобы сократить количество строк. Перепрыгнув к другой реализации, я указанного момента не учел. Спс